# How to print out or iterate for each event listener attached to element?

Tags: jquery, dom, listener, dom-events

How would one print out to console, or iterate for each event listener that is attached to specific DOM element?

I have tried using `.eventListenerList` but I am getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$('#elem').data('events')
```

**[update:](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/)**

> .data(“events”): jQuery stores its event-related data in a data object
>   named (wait for it) events on each element. This is an internal data
>   structure so in 1.8 this will be removed from the user data name space
>   so it won’t conflict with items of the same name. jQuery’s event data
>   can still be accessed via jQuery._data(element, "events") but be aware
>   that this is an internal data structure that is undocumented and
>   should not be modified.

So according to the data from the doc, if you use jquery version > 1.8 then you should follow this method to retrieve informations

```
$._data($('elem')[0],'events')
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/89g4p/)